# Are there cases in which Array.isArray() doesn't work?

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

So I've been trying to debug a physics engine I'm writing, and for a multi-dimensional spatial hashmap I'm needing to allocate a 2D array of arrays.

Why does this code give me "Cannot read property 'push' of undefined"? Is there something happening in the line between my if statements and my trying to push on to the array?

**EDIT** "this" refers to a PhysicsEngine instance, it keeps a reference to the "entities" array as well as a "hashmap" array.

```
function PhysicsEngine(game) {
    this.game = game;
    this.entities = [];
    this.hashmap = createArray(32, 32);
}

for(var i = 0; i < this.entities.length; i++) {
    //Array item may not be a Simulateable Entity
    //this.entities[i].simulatePhysics(this);
    this.entities[i].ResolveCollisions();
    this.entities[i].Move();
    hmx = Math.round(Math.abs(this.entities[i].x/32));
    hmy = Math.round(Math.abs(this.entities[i].y/32));

    if(!logged) {
      console.log(this.hashmap);
      console.log(this.entities[i]);
      console.log(i, hmx, hmy);
      console.log(this.hashmap[hmx], this.hashmap[hmy]);
      logged = true;
    }

    if(!Array.isArray(this.hashmap[hmx])) {
      this.hashmap[hmx] = [];
      if(!Array.isArray(this.hashmap[hmx][hmy])) {
        this.hashmap[hmx][hmy] = [];
      }
    }

    this.hashmap[hmx][hmy].push(this.entities[i]);
}
```

Comment: Nice one. Can you kindly explain the `this` used here with a reference to your full code?

Comment: What if `hmx` is an array, but `hmy` isn't?

Comment: Where is `this.hashmap` defined?

Comment: @SLaks nailed it. Simple logic error!

Comment: @SLaks Both hmx and hmy should be indices, and the second if() should take care of the case that this.hashmap[hmx][hmy] isn't an array I think? Correct me if I'm wrong though, thank you for the help guys

Comment: @AndrueAnderson: Read carefully and figure out when the second `if` will run

Comment: Ah okay, I see the error now. Thanks guys. I appreciate it. Too early in the morning to be working on this heavy stuff without my coffee.

Comment: No coffee?! That's completely irresponsible! Bits could have died!

Answer (score 2):

I think that this code:

```
this.hashmap[hmx] = [];
      if(!Array.isArray(this.hashmap[hmx][hmy])) {
        this.hashmap[hmx][hmy] = [];
      }
```

is not correct. In particular, the "if" condition tests whether this.hashmap[hmx][hmy] is an array. The problem is that this.hashmap[hmx]=[] (as you have set one line before), so this.hashmap[hmx][hmy] is undefined and javascript throws an error "Undefined is not an object".

Maybe is this the problem?

Comment: Thank you, that was the problem. Although I can't actually give you an upvote here because someone previously answered the same thing in the comments above. I do appreciate your time though.